# AngularJS on click table filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am beginner in angularjs, I am trying to apply filter on click, user selects source and destination and will click on filter button, then the table should return as per the input, on page load the table should have values already mentioned in js,

here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="r-filter input-group col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="form-group clearfix">
          <label for="sel1" class="left">Search by Location</label>
          <select class="left form-control" id="source" ng-model="source">
          <option>Select Source</option>
          <option>Mumbai</option>
          <option>Pune</option>
          <option>Goa</option>
          </select>
          <select class="left form-control" id="destn" ng-model="destn">
          <option>Select Destination</option>
          <option>Mumbai</option>
          <option>Pune</option>
          <option>Goa</option>
          </select>
          <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" ng-click="filterfunc()">Filter</button>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="" >
        <table class="table table-striped table-reponsive table-bordered bus-chart-table">
          <thead >
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">Location</th>
              <th colspan="3">Bus Fare</th>
              <th rowspan="2"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>From</th>
              <th>To</th>
              <th>Ordinary(Price in Rs.)</th>
              <th>Semi-Deluxe(Price in Rs.)</th>
              <th>Deluxe(Price in Rs.)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody >
            <tr ng-repeat="record in records | busChartFilter: source: destn">
              <td>{{record.dept}}</td>
              <td>{{record.arr}}</td>
              <td>{{record.ordprice}}</td>
              <td>{{record.sdprice}}</td>
              <td>{{record.dprice}}</td>
              <td><a href="#">Book Now</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>


        </table>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
AppControllers.filter('busChartFilter', function(){

    return function(records,source, destn){
        debugger

        var filteredData= [];
        for( var i=0; i<=records.length; i++){
            var record=records[i];
            if(source==record.dept && destn==record.arr){
                filteredData.push(record);
            }
        }
        return filteredData;
    }
})

AppControllers.controller("chartController", function($scope){

    $scope.beforefilter={};

    $scope.records = [
        { dept: 'Mumbai', arr: 'Goa', ordprice: 700, sdprice: 1000, dprice:1500 },
        { dept: 'Mumbai', arr: 'Goa', ordprice: 700, sdprice: 1000, dprice:1500 },
        { dept: 'Mumbai', arr: 'Pune', ordprice: 400, sdprice: 800, dprice:1000 },
        { dept: 'Goa', arr: 'Mumbai', ordprice: 700, sdprice: 1000, dprice:1500 },
        { dept: 'Goa', arr: 'Pune', ordprice: 400, sdprice: 800, dprice:1000 },
        { dept: 'Pune', arr: 'Mumbai', ordprice: 700, sdprice: 1000, dprice:1500 },
        { dept: 'Pune', arr: 'Goa', ordprice: 400, sdprice: 800, dprice:1000 }
    ];

});
```

thank u in advance

Comment: By the way, you don't need Filter button. The table is automatically filtered when user selects source and destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes -

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevs5749/)

```
app.filter('busChartFilter', function(){

    return function(records,source, destn){
        debugger

        var filteredData= [];
        if((source=='' || source==undefined)  && (destn == ''|| destn==undefined))
         return records;
        for( var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
            var record=records[i];
            if(source==record.dept && destn==record.arr){
                filteredData.push(record);
            }
        }

        return filteredData;
    }
})
```

Comment: welcome.. you can accept it if its usefull to you.. (by clicking on the tick)

Comment: what does the `debugger` do ? in the first line of the function?